# How to restrict the access of dash application to a single user at a given point in time?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a dash python web application and I would like to restrict the access of this application to a single user at a given point in time. How can I achieve that? Is there a way to get an event when a second user tries to access it?

Comment: You could implement some kind of login system. You could use something like Flask Login. Then you could have some persistent state that keeps track if there is a user logged in. You could persist it in a database for example. Then you could create checks each time someone tries to log in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to achieve it with basic authentication using Dash-Auth?

Comment: You can also use Dash Auth for authentication instead of Flask Login, but either way you will probably still need some persistence layer to track login status across different users. Dash Auth checks for the current user if the credentials match, but as far as I know it doesn't keep track of all logged in users. Dash Auth lets you detect if a user is authenticated, but you need a mechanism so other users also know that another user is authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented something similar some time ago.
Basically, i changed the rendered layout, based on time conditions.
For my case, i wanted to make my app working within working hours. ( from 08:00 to 19:00).

```
@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), [Input("url", "pathname")])
def render_page_content(pathname):
    # ---------------------------------------------------
    if pathname == "/":
        # define working time for MILF services
        day_of_week = date.today().strftime("%A")
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        working_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
        if day_of_week in working_days and (now.hour >= 8) and (now.hour < 19):
            # if working time is ok, render App page
            layout = html.Div([tab01.layout])
        else:
            # if working time is closed, render an Info Page
            layout = dcc.Markdown('''
            ### APP is not working now... See you soon !
             ###### Opening time : Monday - Friday 
             ###### Opening hours : 08:00 - 19:00
            '''),
        return layout
```

When conditions are not met, i print the message : **"APP is not working now... See you soon !"**